Why is OAuth2 Token missing scopes?

I'm trying to get a list of users in a google test domain.
Using Powershell and PSGSuite. I'm trying to work through the process.

I've created a project added the Admin API enabled the following scopes in the OAuth2 consent form that are in the code, and when called it does pop a web page asking for the account and for agreement of a wide set of permissions (but doesn't ask again once done, unless a scope is changed):
Import-Module -Name PSGSuite 
-- Removed config line

$Scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
    https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/,
    https://mail.google.com/,
    https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement.readonly,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

$Token = Get-GSToken -Scopes $Scopes -AdminEmail "Removed"
Write-Host "$($Token)"
Get-GSUser -Filter *

the permissions are probably more than I need, but I get a return token:
that when I post to here https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=
returns:
{
  "issued_to": "Removed both were same and correct for app",
  "audience": "Removed both were same and correct for app",
  "scope": "https://mail.google.com https://www.google.com/m8/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly",
  "expires_in": 3549,
  "access_type": "offline"
}

showing my scope of permissions desired is not what I got.
the final command returns an error:
Get-GSUser : Exception calling "Execute" with "0" argument(s): "Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:"""
Any thoughts on why the missing permissions?  maybe I missed a button somewhere.

revoke the users access and request it again

something like this?
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/signOut

more like this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke

same outcome.  I've been able to completely reproduce, here are the general steps

Create Project
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=
Enable Admin SDK API, set oauth consent screen including the the permissions (I named them the same)
Create Oauth 2.0 ClientID - I used same name, generated the json file, and d/l.  I used this as the configuration for PSGSuite.
Google Admin -> Security -> Api Controls -> Domain-wide Delegation
added app with client id from the credentials (not the app name but the client ID) and added the same permisions.  Test


I'm getting a different error though,
Errors [
 Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

which with permissions returned makes sense, but not why I don't get the permissions.
